# Every non-zero element of order of a number field belongs to finitely many prime ideals

Tags: solution-verification, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $K$ be a number field and  $\mathcal{O}$ be an order of $K$. If $0\neq x \in \mathcal{O}$ then is it true that $x$ belongs to only a finite number of prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}$?

Since $\mathcal{O}$ is noetherian every ideal has a primary decomposition. Let
\begin{equation}
(x)=\mathfrak{q}_1\cap\mathfrak{q}_2 \cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{q}_n
\end{equation}
be the primary decomposition of the ideal generated by $x$, where $\mathfrak{q}_i$ are primary ideals. Suppose $(x) \subset \mathfrak{p}$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. From the above equation we have,
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{q}_1\cap\mathfrak{q}_2 \cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{q}_n \subset \mathfrak{p}
\end{align*}
Taking radical on both sides and noting that the radical of a prime ideal is itself and the radical of a primary ideal $\mathfrak{q}_i$ is prime (call it $\mathfrak{p}_i$) We get the following equation.
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{p}_1\cap\mathfrak{p}_2 \cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{p}_n \subset \mathfrak{p}
\end{align*}
By prime avoidance lemma the above equation implies $\mathfrak{p}_i \subset \mathfrak{p}$ for some $i$. Since in an order every prime ideal is maximal $\mathfrak{p}_i = \mathfrak{p}$.

Is the above proof correct? Is there an alternate proof which does not require one to know primary decomposition in Noetherian rings but uses properties of Dedekind domains and order alone (like the index of the ideal in $\mathcal{O}$ in finite and that $\mathcal{O}$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$ module)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks fine to me, but I agree that it feels like overkill to use primary decomposition.

Here's an alternate proof that doesn't use primary decomposition: Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring, and let $x \in R$ be arbitrary. Prime ideals containing $x$ correspond to prime ideals of $R/(x)$, which is also Noetherian. The prime spectrum of a Noetherian ring is a [Noetherian space](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0050) (that is, it satisfies the descending chain condition on closed subsets), which has only finitely many irreducible components, and the irreducible components correspond to minimal prime ideals. So $R/(x)$ has only finitely many minimal prime ideals.

If $R$ is a one-dimensional integral domain and $x$ is nonzero, then $R/(x)$ is zero-dimensional, so all prime ideals of $R/(x)$ are minimal, and we get the result you want. (There's no need to use more properties of Dedekind domains than this.)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. Do primary ideals correspond to irreducible sets in $Spec(R)$? Assuming my previous question is true, you are not using that fact in your proof right? (As you have shown that it is enough to know only the irreducible components).

Comment: *Prime* ideals correspond to irreducible closed subsets of the prime spectrum. This is because prime spectra are *sober spaces*: every irreducible closed subset has a unique generic point. This is used in the proof when we note that irreducible components (that is, maximal irreducible subsets) correspond to minimal prime ideals.

Comment: Thank you very much.